# Setting a height in a View and ignoring safe top edge

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to display an `MKMapView` with a height that is the half of the screen's height and ignoring the top edge. This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
                .border(Color.red, width: 1)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
          //      .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)

            Image("turtlerock")
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1))

            Text("Test")
                .font(.title)

        }
    }
}
```

I commented out the frame method. These are the results when executing the above code (left image), and with the frame method not commented out (right image):

[image][image]

We can examine that the left image, so without the frame method, the edges are ignored at the top which is good. At the right image with the applied frame height method, the top edge isn't ignored anymore.

From my understanding the order of modifiers applied to views is important. I tried various orders, but I can't figure it out how to create the MapView view with half of the height's screen height and ignoring the top edge. The MapView struct is defined as follows:

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct MapView : UIViewRepresentable {
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011286, longitude: -116.166868)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)

        uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use [`relativeHeight(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3278642-relativeheight) instead?

Comment: @user28434 I tried that also, but it is relative to its parent height. I get very strange height's when using that method. Using this method: .relativeHeight(0.5) on the MapView view, the view get's very small...

Comment: Also, you can try `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` on your top view.

Comment: @user28434 yes i already did, i include the code so people can reproduce this view within seconds

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I just needed to add a Spacer() at the very end:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
                .border(Color.red, width: 1)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)

            Image("turtlerock")
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1))

            Text("Test")
                .font(.title)

            Spacer() // New line
        }
    }
}
```